# rails g scaffold teacher name, email - Giving error: NoMethodError at /teachers/new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two contollers:
students_controller.rb
teachers_controller.rb

Both of these controllers are generated with scaffolding. When I started the server, students's view /students/new is loading just fine but /teachers/new is giving me some error:

**Error:**

> NoMethodError in TeachersController#new
>
> undefined method `attribute_method_matcher' for nil:NilClass
>   Rails.root: /Users/pdahal/RubyOnRails/apps/myapplication
>
> Application Trace  app/controllers/teachers_controller.rb:27:in `new'
>   app/controllers/teachers_controller.rb:27:in`new'

**teachers_controller.rb:**

```
# GET /teachers/new
# GET /teachers/new.json
  def new
    @teacher = Teacher.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @teacher }
    end
```

**students_controller.rb**

```
  # GET /students/new
  # GET /students/new.json
  def new
    @student = Student.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @student }
    end
  end
```

**new.html.erb :**

```
<%- model_class = Teacher -%>
<div class="page-header">
  <h1><%=t '.title', :default => [:'helpers.titles.new', 'New %{model}'], :model => model_class.model_name.human.titleize %></h1>
</div>
<%= render :partial => 'form' %>
```

**db/schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20131113051714) do

  create_table "students", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "age"
    t.string   "sex"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "major"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "teachers", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "age"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "sex"
    t.string   "class"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end
```

students_controller.rb has the exact same codes and is working just fine. Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your view new.html.erb

Comment: can you paste the whole error message?

Comment: Hi ^^ I have pasted new.html.erb and error message. Thanks!

Comment: I'd want to see the `db/schema.rb` file. I think you may trying to use a reserved keyword as a database column for the teachers table.

Comment: @KevinSjöberg, I think you are right, I have "class" (possibly reserved) on teachers's table. I will try to change it to something other than class, course perhaps and give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: `class` is definitely a reserved word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because I had used reserved word `class` on :

```
create_table "teachers", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "age"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "sex"
    t.string   "class"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end
```

I deleted that scaffold and regenerated new:

```
rails g teacher name age:integer email sex course 
#replaced class with course, now its working great.
```

Thanks!